# How to do a search that matches all todo's except a specific one?

Tags: org-mode

I want to find all todo's except type TASK without having to list all the other types.

I tried the following but no luck:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '( ("h" "Everything not a task"
 ( (todo "-TASK")))))
```

Gives an empty list.

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '( ("h" "Everything not a task"
 ( (todo ".*|-TASK")))))
```

Gives me everything, also TASK

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '( ("h" "Everything not a task"
 ( (todo "TODO|-TASK")))))
```

Gives me all TODO, and not TASK but I don't want to also maintain the list of types here.

Answer (score 5):

This should return all todo's except those with a today keyword of TASK

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '( ("h" "Everything not a task"
                                     ( (tags-todo "+TODO<>\"TASK\"")))))
```

you could also use

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '( ("h" "Everything not a task"
                                     ( (tags-todo "/-TASK")))))
```

This is based on the documentation [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html).

Comment: Would that also include my INPROGEsS todos?

Comment: Trying to grok that syntax while I'm still on mobile.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, is TASK a tag or a TODO keyword that you're trying to avoid?  This will pull all TODO's except those that are a TODO keyword of TASK

Comment: It's basically just +TODO<>"TASK" , see "Limit tags and properties searches by TODO state" on http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html

Comment: it is a TODO Keyword.

now at laptop and I can see it works - so thats great :)

I now just wonder what the meaning of +/- syntax is that is described in org-mode manual.

I haven't seen the <> before, but seems good ;)

Comment: I added an example using the +/- syntax as well.  Check out the linked page for more info